# Use the levels of a dataframe column to add a new column with an incrementing number unique to each level

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm trying to create a new column in a dataframe that contains an incrementing number based on the levels of a different column. That is, I want to rename the levels of a column so that each level has a unique, incrementing number.

```
df <- data.frame(y1 = c(100, 100, 100, 200, 200, 500, 500, 500),
                 y2 = c(6, 5, 4, 2, 5, 4, 3, 2))
df$y1 <- as.factor(df$y1)
levels(df$y1) ## [1] "100" "200" "500"
```

Expected output: a new y3 column with new level names based on the levels of y1. The "b" isn't necessary, I can add that on later.

```
y1    y2    y3
100   6     b1
100   5     b1
100   4     b1
200   2     b2
200   5     b2
500   4     b3
500   3     b3
500   2     b3
```

I've messed around with `lapply` and various `for` loops, but I don't really know what I'm doing here... stuff like this:

```
for (i in levels(df$y1)){
    batchnum <- 1
    if (i == df$y1){
        df$y3 <- paste0("b", batchnum)
        batchnum <- batchnum + 1
    }
}
```

This just labels y3 with "b1" for each row, I guess because `if` is not vectorized or something?

```
## Warning messages:
1: In if (i == df$y1) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)
df[, y3 := .GRP, by = y1]
df[, y3 := paste0("b", y3)] # you can change "b" with whatever you want

    y1 y2 y3
1: 100  6 b1
2: 100  5 b1
3: 100  4 b1
4: 200  2 b2
5: 200  5 b2
6: 500  4 b3
7: 500  3 b3
8: 500  2 b3
```

Comment: Or just `df[, y3 := paste0('b', .GRP), by = y1]`

Answer (score 3):

A `dplyr` approach:

```
require(dplyr);
df %>% mutate(y3 = paste0("b", as.numeric(y1)));
#   y1 y2 y3
#1 100  6 b1
#2 100  5 b1
#3 100  4 b1
#4 200  2 b2
#5 200  5 b2
#6 500  4 b3
#7 500  3 b3
#8 500  2 b3
```

Or you also do:

```
df %>% mutate(y3 = paste0("b", cumsum(!duplicated(y1))));
#   y1 y2 y3
#1 100  6 b1
#2 100  5 b1
#3 100  4 b1
#4 200  2 b2
#5 200  5 b2
#6 500  4 b3
#7 500  3 b3
#8 500  2 b3
```

Comment: I got a chance to use `group_indices` to get new column:-)

Answer (score 3):

The most direct and simple approach (taking advantage of the fact that `as.numeric` will generate numbers corresponding to the factor levels):

```
df$y3 <- paste0('b', as.numeric(df$y1))
```

If it's not clear why this works, look at the following code on its own:

```
as.numeric(df$y1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way:

```
x <- c(100,100,100,200,200,500,500,500)
paste0("b",rep(seq_along(table(x)),table(x)))
[1] "b1" "b1" "b1" "b2" "b2" "b3" "b3" "b3"
```

Answer (score 1):

One can use `group_indices` function from `dplyr` to create new column as:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(y3 = paste0("b", group_indices(.,y1)))

#   y1 y2 y3
#1 100  6 b1
#2 100  5 b1
#3 100  4 b1
#4 200  2 b2
#5 200  5 b2
#6 500  4 b3
#7 500  3 b3
#8 500  2 b3
```

Comment: Or another possibility: `df %>% mutate(y3 = paste0("b", cumsum(!duplicated(y1))));`